# Чтение access_log apache и вывод в админку сайта

Tags: php, centos7, httpd

Как реализовать доступ и чтение файла логов запросов на сервере centOs 7 /var/log/httpd/access_log средствами php и вывод содержимого в админку сайта, находящегося в каталоге /var/www/user/site, при этом  чтобы соответствующий скрипт находился в каталоге сайта /var/www/user/site?
Я полагаю,что нужно пользоваться функцией system(), но как в таком случае быть с доступом,разрешениями и паролями и т.п., ведь access_log имеет ограниченные разрешения

Comment: Как минимум не делать так.

Comment: Почему???небезопасно?

Comment: Потому что вы хотите заставить "дочерний" процесс "забирать" файл у родителя, причем чаще всего во время записи родителем оного =)

Comment: Почему во время записи! Мне нужно прочесть уже существующие файлы, а "родственные" отношения здесь не причем...

Comment: Т.е. вы читаете не access_log в который пишет апач? тогда не вижу никаких сложностей... если же вы читаете access_log в который пишет апач - то вы делаете это "одновременно" с тем как он пишет =)

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: Если очень хочется - делайте как есть, просто читайте файл, он доступен на чтение... но глюки могут быть =)

Comment: Вообще то в директории httpd если посмотреть этих access_log файлов куча и они все именуются по датам

Comment: Вообщето это зависит от настроек вашего апача =) у меня файл один за все даты =) но свой для каждого домена =) как настроено у вас (тем более что название вы указали статично, без намека на даты) - мне не видно отсюда =)